# Prevent App Nap is disabled

Tags: applications

An Application I have (IntelliJ Idea to be more specific) has Prevent App Nap checked but the checkbox is disabled and I can not disable Prevent App Nap.

How can I disable "Prevent App Nap" for this application?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't uncheck it, the app doesn't support it. App Nap requires support from the developer in the app for it to be available. In this case, IDEA is a Java app which doesn't support App Nap.